# FusedLocationProviderClient and GpsStatus suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am using FusedLocationproviderClient to get my current location and

`GpsStatus.Listener` to get the Gps Status using this code:

```
 @Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int i) {

    switch (i){
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") GpsStatus status= mLocationManager.getGpsStatus(null);


            int satsused = 0;

            Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats=status.getSatellites();
            for (GpsSatellite sat: sats){

                if (sat.usedInFix()){
                    satsused++;
                }
            }
            textview.setText(String.valueOf(satsused));

            if (satsused==0){




                ////

            }

            break;




    }

}
```

This code is working fine but a few days back my phone software got crashed so I have flashed my phone to install a new software for my phone. Now my phone is working but when I tried to run this code in my app again this time the app is not working it is neither giving me current location nor Gps Status. I have also made sure that my `GooglePlayService` version is latest because FusedLocationProviderClient is based on `GooglePlayService`.

My app on other devices is working fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Same issue here. How did you solve this?